# New to pig, how can i know what underlying mapreduce jobs run for my pig script ? how to debug result output of pig script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

New to pig, how can I know what underlying mapreduce jobs run for my pig script ? how to debug-trace result output of pig script ?

Comment: You can look at the YARN UI to see the MapReduce stages (assuming you are using YARN). And you debug by dumping the relations

Answer (score 0):

you cau use yarn when starting pig with this command pig -x tez . 
Next you can use YARN UI to see the mapreduce jobs